# New Snowflake UI - Query Status

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The classic UI would indicate a query's status by showing a red X, blue swirl, or green check mark in the worksheet tab. Does the new UI have anything similar?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowsight does not show execution status in Worksheet **tab** level. You'd need get into each Worksheet **file**.

To see the Status of all running queries in parallel, you can always go to the Query History tab

Comment: Sucks that it doesn't have that feature. That's one feature in the classic UI that I like. Thank you.